# ..., have you? / ..., and you? (at the end of the question)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Do these sentences have the same meaning, or is there a nuance? Is the second version more common?

> 'I have never played this game, **have you?**' 'I haven’t played this one either.'
>
> 'I have never played this game, **and you?** 'I haven’t played this one either.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first would seem more natural, but the question "Have you?" is a separate question, not a tag.  It should be in its own sentence.  In writing that means a full stop and capital letter  "...this game. Have you?" In speech there would be a pause and an intonation pattern.

The "and you" might occur as part of a conversation, but it seems rather artificial.  "And you" is more common in sentences about our feelings or internal states.  "How are you? / I'm well, and you?"